# Resubmit a Form when connection is lost in Android

Tags: android, forms, webview, form-submit

I am trying to implement an app, that uses WebView to show a website which has a form inside. The problem is, when user fills the form and just before the Send button is pressed, the internet connection is lost. In this case, I receive onErrorReceived callback, and here is my implementation:

```java
@Override
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
    mDisconnected = true;
    mDisconnectUrl = failingUrl;
    mWebView = view;
    mWebView.saveState(mWebViewState);
}
```

So I try to store the content of the form here and the failing url, so I can continue sending it when the connection established again. So I have another thread trying to make a new Socket connection with the server, and when it succeeds, I call a function in my WebViewClient class reconnect():

```java
void reconnect(Context appContext) {
    if (mDisconnected) {
        try {
            ((Activity) appContext).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    mWebView.reload();
                    mWebView.restoreState(mWebViewState);
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        }
        mDisconnected = false;
    }
}
```

So I try to make a reload and restore the form data so the WebView can continue with its send operation. The problem is when the page is again loaded, all the data entered in the form are lost and it does not continue with the Send operation, which was already clicked before the connection is lost. Has any one any idea, how to solve this problem.

The data is very sensitive, so it is important to continue with sending. It is also possible to let the user fill the form again and send it again, but it is not wanted in this scenario.

**EDIT:**
Maybe the question can be simplified. Is there any function or way to refresh a website in WebViewClient, which continues where it was left of and retrieves the form data into the state before the problem was occured.

Comment: can you provide the code that submits the data?

Comment: does `shouldInterceptRequest (WebView view, String url)` give you the URL that must be retrieved? Or maybe `shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url)`... If neither helps, maybe, it's sending the dontResend action from `onFormResubmission (WebView view, Message dontResend, Message resend)`?

Comment: @Snippet: What do you mean by the code that submits the data. It is the web site, it can be any web site, I do not have the code. I am also not allowed to use java script injection.

Comment: `shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url)` is not called because the send button uses POST method. I will try `shouldInterceptRequest (WebView view, String url)` and update the post. I think `onFormResubmission (WebView view, Message dontResend, Message resend)` is called only when the loaded page is the result of a POST, so in this case it is never called.

Answer (score 1):

Use database to store the contents of form and then send the data through service.
Delete the contents of database upon successfull submission.

Comment: Can you be more specific, and give some examples?

Comment: If you have any idea about sqlite use that database to store the contents of form. Now create a service that runs all the time .In this service create a method that checks if database has some data .If yes then send the data through multipart entity and httpPost. And truncate the table once the response is 200. Sorry,I dont have any example to show up.

Comment: I have no idea about sqlite, but is it possible to save the form data without knowing anything about the website code. The website can be any website, that my customer create. I cant know source code of all.

Comment: You need to get API that has to be either in XML or JSON to access the data.Otherwise its not possible.